# How to generate unique username - PHP

Tags: php

I have strings of usernames in array . I want to generate a unique string of username which do  not exits in array.(probably with some numbers following the username)

How do I achieve this?

I have summarize the code:

```
function generate_unique_username(){
    $firstname      = "james";//data coming from user
    $lastname       = "oduro";//data coming from user
    $new_username   = $firstname.$lastname;
    $usersnames     = array("james39","oduro32","kwame93","elvisasante","frimpong32","edward32","jamesoduro");

    //Loop through ARRAY usernames and check elements against VAR $new_username

    if (in_array($new_username, $usersnames)) {
        //generate new username which is not inside array
        //the new generated string should also be check against array to ensure is doens not exit.


    }else{
        return $new_username;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your solution will not scale well. With this sort of flow, you will need to get all usernames that exist in your database, store them in array, and check against the entire array. If your website gets 10-50k users (even if 99% are inactive), performance of registration page will be severely degraded.

Comment: pre-production version `$i=0; do  {$new_username_full =  $new_username.mt_rand(1,99999); } while(in_array($new_username_full,$usernames) && $i++<9000)` if after 9000 tryouts no name was found it breaks, but @dimi has a real good argument

Comment: The question is: *why?* If this is db-related, you should create a UNIQUE index on email addresses instead. @jamesOduro

Comment: I can see you're concatenating variable $new_username with a random number. I think there's still a problem here......how will u be sure  the new generated is already inside or not??

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes the project is database related.

Comment: I feel you're going to be using more resources than required and querying could be an issue. As I said in my previous comment, I think it would be best if you were to create a UNIQUE index on an email (address) column, but that's just *"my 2 cents"* here. If it's for a sign up page, you could use a verifying link containing an encoded version of it (email address), and a one time token key. Again; just a suggestion. @jamesOduro

Comment: If you go through with this idea, be sure to check against existing names directly in the database and not load all the names and loop through them with PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Generating username from the stored array is not a good practice, I would suggest you to use the database.

If you are using the database instead of the array, you can use the best method to generate the unique username as following:

```
function generate_unique_username(){
    $firstname      = "james";//data coming from user
    $lastname       = "oduro";//data coming from user
    $new_username   = $firstname.$lastname;

    /* Note: writing here pseudo sql code, replace with the actual php mysql query syntax */
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) as user_count FROM user WHERE username like '%".$new_username."%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $count = $result['user_count'];

    if(!empty($count)) {
        $new_username = $new_username . $count;
    }

    return $new_username;
}
```

Comment: The code shown in this answer assumes none of the usernames already used is equal to `$firstname . $lastname . $count`. It cannot warrant the username is unique.

Comment: For example, there could be 5 usernames starting with _jamesoduro_ and one of them be _jamesoduro5_. This code would suggest _jamesduro5_, which is already used. Even using `$count + 1` instead of `$count` would make a difference, since one of those usernames could be _jamesoduro6_.

Comment: Hi @kiamlaluno, if there are 5 usernames starting with `jamesoduro`, if you notice the query, it will fetch the count of that user's first and last name combination, so it will always ensure the unique username.

Comment: It works only when all the usernames are generated with that function and cannot be changed later. Otherwise, counting how many usernames contain _jamesoduro_ and adding that number after the name doesn't create a unique username. For example, the usernames already in the database are _jamesoduro1_, _jamesoduro2_, _jamesoduro3_, _jamesoduro5_, _jamesoduro6_. The names are 5, so that function would suggest _jamesoduro5_, which is already used.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you should first off try and assign cooler user names to the users then when that fails you go for a number suffix. This is an approach I may use. You may need to change the code to your more preferred and secured mysqli call like using the PDO or MySQLI prepared statement.

```
//function that will be used to figure out if the user name is available or not
function isAvailable($userName){
    global $mysqli;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'") or die($mysqli->error());

    // We know username exists if the rows returned are more than 0
    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
         //echo 'User with this username already exists!';
         return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

function generate_unique_username($firstname, $lastname, $id){    
    $userNamesList = array();
    $firstChar = str_split($firstname, 1)[0];
    $firstTwoChar = str_split($firstname, 2)[0];
    /**
     * an array of numbers that may be used as suffix for the user names index 0 would be the year
     * and index 1, 2 and 3 would be month, day and hour respectively.
     */
    $numSufix = explode('-', date('Y-m-d-H')); 

    // create an array of nice possible user names from the first name and last name
    array_push($userNamesList, 
        $firstname,                 //james
        $lastname,                 // oduro
        $firstname.$lastname,       //jamesoduro
        $firstname.'.'.$lastname,   //james.oduro
        $firstname.'-'.$lastname,   //james-oduro
        $firstChar.$lastname,       //joduro
        $firstTwoChar.$lastname,    //jaoduro,
        $firstname.$numSufix[0],    //james2019
        $firstname.$numSufix[1],    //james12 i.e the month of reg
        $firstname.$numSufix[2],    //james28 i.e the day of reg
        $firstname.$numSufix[3]     //james13 i.e the hour of day of reg
    );


    $isAvailable = false; //initialize available with false
    $index = 0;
    $maxIndex = count($userNamesList) - 1;

    // loop through all the userNameList and find the one that is available
    do {
        $availableUserName = $userNamesList[$index];
        $isAvailable = isAvailable($availableUserName);
        $limit =  $index >= $maxIndex;
        $index += 1;
        if($limit){
        break;
        }
    } while (!$isAvailable );

    // if all of them is not available concatenate the first name with the user unique id from the database
    // Since no two rows can have the same id. this will sure give a unique username
    if(!$isAvailable){
        return $firstname.$userId;
    }
    return $availableUserName;
}

//Get the unique user id from your database, for now let's go with 30
$userId = 30;
echo generate_unique_username('john', 'oduro', $userId);
```

Also, it would be nice to provide a fallback feature where the user can change their user name to any other unique value, in case they do not like the auto-generated value.